# What is this smoke coming from an airplane wing when it is landing?

Tags: landing

I noticed that when an airplane is landing, the end of the wing emits a smoke like the one here: [image: sample].

What is that?

Comment: It's a vapor trail. See also http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14539/what-causes-a-planes-wing-tips-to-leave-a-small-white-vapor-trail?s=2|1.0543

Comment: Yep, it's the wing tip vortex.